# How to run a script before flutter run and flutter build

Tags: android, flutter

Because of flutter use yaml file. Compared to gradle it's too inflexible. We need dynamic change the yaml file so I found someway that execute a bash script before "flutter run" and "flutter build".

I can execute a bash script in gitlab-ci.yaml which have a property of "script:xxx/xxx.sh". I can execute it before "flutter build apk". So it work in gitlab. But I can't get someway to execute the script in local before I execute "flutter run"

Anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: No need to put down flutter, etc. Just ask your question. I believe you want to know how to execute a bash file before flutter run. It would help to know: what is your local environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a scripts.sh file in your project and run the scripts file instead of flutter run command. The scripts file will have the scripts to run before, call to flutter run and scripts to run after. Example of a sample script file.

```
echo "Start Run" 
flutter run 
echo "End Run"
```

Comment: Do it will lose a lot. And other developer must be not disagree this solution. It only can use in gitlab CI script. Thank you for your proposal~

Answer (score 1):

A compatible solution. We can `Eidt Configuration` and add a `Before launch`. But I think it's not a best solution.